# How to make paginaton via ajax Django?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

let's say I have to sort, it works, everything is displayed, but I can not do pagination, it turns out, I have absolutely all the goods, sorted items, it turns out that there are 200 objects, and they are all displayed, how to make it about 9, that is, 9 objects were displayed, then click on the next link, and next the following products were output from the sorted categories !?

```
def sorting_by_ajax(request):
    return_dict                 = {}
    data = request.POST
    categorys_slug              = data.get("category_slug")
    category_of_relation_sheps  = data.get("category_of_relationsheep")
    if len(data.getlist('categoryes[]')) == 0:
        categoryes_list         = data.get('categoryes')
    else:
        categoryes_list         = data.getlist('categoryes[]')

    if len(data.getlist('brands[]')) == 0:
        brands_list = data.get("brands")
    else:
        brands_list             = data.getlist('brands[]')
    discount_list               = data.get("discount_list")
    product_himself_list        = Product.objects.filter(refers_to__name_of_category__in=categoryes_list, brand__name_of_brand__in=brands_list)
    paginator                   = Paginator(product_himself_list, 9) # Show 25 contacts per page
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        product_himself         = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
        product_himself         = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
        product_himself         = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    return_dict["products"] = list()
    for product in product_himself_list:
        new_product = {}
        new_product["product_id"] = product.id
        new_product["product_brand"] = product.brand.name_of_brand
        new_product["product_name"] = product.name_of_product
        new_product["product_id"] = product.quantity_of_goods
        if product.discount:
            new_product["product_price"] = product.price_with_discount
        else:
            new_product["product_price"] = product.price_of_product
        new_product["product_slug"] = product.product_slug
        new_product["product_description"] = product.description
        new_product["product_image"] = product.poster_image.url
        for i in product.size_of_product.all():
            if i == 'M':
                new_product["product_size_m"] = i
            elif i == 'S':
                new_product["product_size_s"] = i
            elif i == "L":
                new_product["product_size_l"] = i
        return_dict["products"].append(new_product)
    print(product_himself_list)
    print(return_dict)

    return JsonResponse(return_dict)
```

Comment: Check out [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/pagination/#using-paginator-in-a-view).

Comment: @SamBobel before writing anything, read the description and code !!